# remove asterisk symbol inside diamond shape

Tags: python, python-2.7

i want to ask about this think
i have a script and it's print a diamond shape like this.

```
Value : 5
          * 
        * * * 
      * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * 
        * * * 
          *
```

the script code is like this

```
masuk = int(input("Value : "))

for jarak in range(1, masuk):
    for jarak6 in range(-1, masuk - jarak):
        print (" ", end=" ")
    for jarak7 in range(1, jarak):
        print ("*", end=" ")
    for jarak8 in range(jarak, 0, -1):
        print ("*", end=" ")

    print()

for jarak in range(1, masuk *2 , + 1):
    for jarak2 in range(jarak):
        print (" ", end=" ")
    for jarak3 in range(jarak, masuk + 1):
        print ("*", end=" ")
    for jarak4 in range(jarak + 1, masuk + 1):
        print ("*", end=" ")

    print()
```

what i want to ask is :

1. is it a effective way to make a diamond shape ?
2. how removing asterisk symbol in the middle of the diamond shape ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loops can be replaced by simple string multiplication. Instead of writing

```
for i in range(a, b):
    print(" ", end=" ")
```

you could just write

```
print("  " * (b - a))
```

With this, you can combine all three inner loops of both your outer loops into one print call:

```
print(" " * num_spaces + "*"*num_asterisks)
```

I'm not sure what you mean by removing the diamond inside the shape though.

Comment: I guess spaces instead of asterisks except at the first and last position.

Comment: i mean i just want a diamond shape with unfilled with any character inside the diamond shape. so it's just like hollow diamond shape.

Comment: In that case, you're going to need an `if` clause: each row will be (a number of spaces) + (an asterisk) + (another number of spaces) + (another asterisk) except the first and last rows, which will just be (a number of spaces) + (an asterisk). For the top half, the first number of spaces will generally be equal to (total number of rows) - (current row number). The second number of spaces (for the empty space on the inside) will be 2*(current row number)-1 spaces.

Comment: okay is it meant that i need an conditional logic inside the looping condition. am i right ?

Comment: Ask a new question if you really cannot figure it out.